# Expo-image-picker crashes app after using launchCameraAsync() on Android

Tags: android, react-native, expo, imagepicker

I'm using expo-image-picker to allow the user to pick and take pictures. Choosing an image from the library works as expected but when using the camera, after taking the picture the app crashes.
Here is my code:

```
const take = async () => {
    let result = await ImagePicker.launchCameraAsync({
      mediaTypes: ImagePicker.MediaTypeOptions.Images,
      quality: 1,
      
    });

    console.log(result.uri);
    if (!result.cancelled) {
      setImageUri(result.uri);
    }
  };
```

I think I have all the required permissions and the problem seems to occur only on older android devices with limited memory. Any ideas?

Comment: Do you see the `uri` getting logged on the screen? Because this is working fine for me. Sho how are you calling the function

Comment: Thank you for replying :) Nothing is being returned from the function. The app crashes without any logs. It seems to occur in old devices with limited memory.

Comment: on the Button which you press to call this `take` function, write this... `onPress={() => console.log("Pressed Button")}` and see whether its getting logged on the console or not

Comment: yes the message is being logged as expected on the console

Comment: Wrap the Picture click logic inside a `try-catch` block. See if it helps. because it's working fine for me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no good and easy solution.

What is happening is, when you launch the camera, it launches as a new `Activity`, leaving your app `mainActivity` in background.

From Android P (9) and on, the OS can kill your background activity. There is even a website just about whose implementation is worse for devs: https://dontkillmyapp.com/

---

Possible solutions:

1. Be prepared to crash. Save all states and navigation stack on local-storage, launchCamera. The app will restart, you will restore all the screen/navigation/data/etc, and get photo using the [`ImagePicker.getPendingResultAsync`](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/v47.0.0/sdk/imagepicker/#imagepickergetpendingresultasync).
2. Change lib to [expo-camera](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/camera/) or [react-native-vision-camera](https://github.com/mrousavy/react-native-vision-camera) as they use the camera on `mainActivity` but needs boring reimplementation, and don' t look as good as the manufacturer native cameras.