# React-native-image-picker crashes in Android 11

Tags: react-native

I have used react-native-image-picker in my project. It is working fine in android phones that are less than Android 11 but App crashes in android 11 without showing logcat. launchImageLibrary is working as expected but launchCamera is crashing app. I have added the permissions also in android manifest file i.e

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

but still no luck.

Comment: Possible a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68206801/expo-image-picker-crashes-app-after-using-launchcameraasync-on-android/74816435#74816435

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed it by adding await in launchImageLibrary/launchCamera
I have added the code for your reference

```js
const openCamera = async () => { 
let options = { quality: 5, maxWidth: 500, maxHeight: 500, includeBase64: true, mediaType: 'photo', noData: true, };

await launchCamera(options, response => { 
if (response.didCancel) { 
console.log('Cancelled');
} else if (response.error) { 
console.log('Error', response.errorMessage);
} else { 
console.log(response); 
setFilePath(response.uri); 
setBase64('data:image/png;base64,' + response.base64); } });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

try to remove

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
```

Image-picker don't need permission