# Why does my flutter app crash when trying to upload an image on Mi phones using image_picker_plus?

Tags: image, file-upload, flutter-dependencies, flutter-image-picker

I am Encountering an issue with Flutter upload image functionality. when I attempt to upload using Mi brand phones, the camera abruptly shuts down and the application restarts. Currently, I am using the Redmi Note 7S, and this problem seems to be specific to Mi phones. On other brands of phones the upload feature works fine.Unfortunately, there are no specific error messages displayed. It showing  loss of device connection in logs. It could possibly be an issue with the Flutter plugin. I am using "image_picker_plus: ^0.5.6+2".

can anyone also facing the same issue or having the solution for it.?

Comment: I have faced similar issues trying to upload images.
Similar: [app crashes with image-picker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68206801/expo-image-picker-crashes-app-after-using-launchcameraasync-on-android)